# Can I access parent scope from inner HTML of an element with an isolate scope attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an attribute directive 'my-isolate-directive' that decorates the value of the HTML element to which it is attached. I made it an isolate scope so I can pass params to it.

But I'd also like to continue referencing objects in the parent scope - e.g. 'outerVar' below - from within the value of the element that has the attribute directive:

```
<div>
    'outerVar' shows! {{outerVar}}
</div>

<div my-isolate-directive my-isolate-directive-param="requiredParam">
    Oops! 'outerVar' does not show! {{outerVar}}
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to use pass the `outerVar` as parameter of the directive (recommended way) or use  `$parent` (e.g. `$parent.outerVar`) to access parent scope (this beat the purpose of isolated scope, through)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't. The purpose of the isolated scope is exactly to prevent what you're trying to achieve, by not inheriting from any other scope. If you wan't to access the parent scopes and still create a new one you should set `scope: true`.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) you can find the documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrés says in his answer, `scope: true` lets your directive have a new scope inherited from the parent.

I will add that if you would like to have attributes without isolate scope, you still can by using something like:

```
attr.$observe('myIsolateDirectiveParam', function(myIsolateDirectiveParam){
    scope.myIsolateDirectiveParam = scope.$eval(myIsolateDirectiveParam);
});
```